# How to wait and get notified for Redux Saga to complete a Success or Error action outside of Redux Store (ex. React Component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

#### Context

I am a new developer. In my React Typescript project, I am trying to use Redux Sagas for the first time.

#### Problem

In my React Project, users will complete a form and submit. This submission is dispatched to start an API call using Redux Saga. After the request is complete and the SUCCESS/FAILURE is put, I need to update the React component appropriately or navigate the user to another page using `useNavigate()`.

#### Senario

I have 3 Action Types for this feature:

```bash
CREATE_TODO_START
CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS
CREATE_TODO_FAILURE
```

A user on the application can create a TODO item using a form.

After submitting the form, the `onFinish` function get triggered:

```js
const onFinish = (newTodo: NewTodoRequest) => {
   // I defined const dispatch = useDispatch()
   dispatch(createTodoStart(newTodo))
}
```

After the user sends the request, it starts my Saga:

```js
function* newTodo({payload}: NewTodoStart) {
    try {
        const {data} = yield* call(createTodo, payload);
        yield* put(createTodoSuccess(data));
    } catch (error) {
        yield* put(createTodoFailure(error as Error));
    }
}
```

These put functions will update my `todoReducer` accordingly:

```js
export type TodoReducer = {
    readonly todos: Todo[],
    readonly isLoading: boolean,
    readonly error: Error | null
}
```

After the `CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS` or `CREATE_TODO_FAILURE` is called and completed, I need to update my react component to either: navigate the user to their TODO dashboard or show an Error message to the user that their TODO was not able to be created for whatever reason.

If anyone has any advice on how to wait for `CREATE_TODO_SUCCESS` or `CREATE_TODO_FAILURE` to be completed outside of the Redux Store (e.g. React Component), that would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to use the `useEffect` hook. Usually waiting for the `isLoading` as the `useEffect` dependency to complete and selecting the `error` from the `todoReducer` would work, but also shows errors that were stored from previous requests or other requests using the `todoReducer`. Navigating the user based on a change from an existing array (`todo[]`) sometimes falsely triggers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Redux maintainer. I would actually recommend making some major changes to how you're building this :)

First, you're writing a very outdated style of Redux code.  Today, you should be using our official Redux Toolkit package to set up your store and write your reducers. That will result in *way* less code, and it will be easier to maintain.  No more writing separate action types like `CREATE_TODO_START/SUCCESS/FAILURE` - RTK eliminates the need to write code like that yourself.

Second, we specifically recommend *against* using sagas in almost all cases, and *especially* for data fetching.  Instead, the best option is to use the "RTK Query" data fetching and caching API that's included in Redux Toolkit.

So, the best option here would be to set up RTK Query in your Redux app, and define a `createTodo` "mutation" endpoint.  That way, you can send the data to the server in your submit handler, and `await` the result, along the lines of:

```
function TodoForm() {
  const [createTodo] = useCreateTodoMutation();

  const onFinish = (newTodo: NewTodoRequest) => {
    await createTodo(newTodo);
    // do navigation here
  }
}
```

Please see our Redux docs tutorials for details on using Redux Toolkit and RTK Query:

- https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations

Comment: I was trying to learn sagas since it felt like they added more structure to the way I sent requests in my client application. Is there a reason why we should move away from `redux-sagas`?

Comment: Yes, multiple reasons: 1) They add unnecessary indirection; 2) they require knowing JS generator functions _and_ the specific `redux-saga` effects; 3) they easily lead to spaghetti event-driven logic that is hard to understand; 4) they don't work well with TS; 5) especially for data fetching, RTK Query _does_ all that for you already. Also see https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/02/blogged-answers-why-redux-toolkit-uses-thunks-for-async-logic/ and https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches .